# Embedabble Kafka commit log only lib

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a case where I need a FIFO persistent queue. The FIFO persistent queue needs to write its data to a disk attached to a machine where the application is running (no network calls). I have found some libraries but I was wondering if Kafka's commit-log only logic can be used standalone without the cluster and the whole distributed part? Possibly being used as a library that can be embedded in the application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run Kafka as only one broker in a cluster, but that is a single point of failure, and therefore not recommended. It can be embedded, but this is typically used for tests, not for real application usage.

It also does require network calls, even if to localhost.

Perhaps SQLite would be a better starting point.